# "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function" with JSON functions

Tags: mysql, json, group-by

I am getting "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function" while attempting to collapse 3 child tables into a JSON column in the parent column.

I know this is a cardinal sin against the Rule of Normalise Everything, but is happens to be what I need.

I have 4 tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `requirement_categories` (
    `requirement_category` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`requirement_category`),
     UNIQUE KEY `category_UNIQUE` (`requirement_category`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `requirement_groups` (
    `requirement_group` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `requirement_category` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`requirement_group`),
     KEY `fk_requirement_caregory_idx` (`requirement_category`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_requirement_caregory` FOREIGN KEY 
     (`requirement_category`) REFERENCES `requirement_categories` 
     (`requirement_category`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `requirement_subgroups` (
    `group_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    `requirement_subgroup` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `description` text,
     `requirement_group` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`requirement_subgroup`),
     KEY `fk_requirement_group_idx` (`requirement_group`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_requirement_group` FOREIGN KEY 
     (`requirement_group`) REFERENCES `requirement_groups` 
     (`requirement_group`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `requirements` (
    `requirement` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `description` text,
    `requirements_subgroup` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`requirement`,`requirements_subgroup`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My query follows:

```
    SELECT 
        rc.requirement_category,
        JSON_OBJECT('requirement_group',
          rg.requirement_group,
          'requirement_subgroup',
          JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('requirement_subgroup',
                        rsg.requirement_subgroup,
                        'description',
                        rsg.description,
                        'requirements',
                        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('requirement',
                                        rs.requirement,
                                        'description',
                                        rs.description))))) AS 
     requirement
    FROM
        jobdesc_jdc.requirement_categories rc
            LEFT JOIN
        requirement_groups rg ON rg.requirement_category = 
    rc.requirement_category
    LEFT JOIN
      requirement_subgroups rsg ON rsg.requirement_group = 
     rg.requirement_group
    LEFT JOIN
      requirements rs ON rs.requirements_subgroup = 
   rsg.requirement_subgroup
  GROUP BY rg.requirement_category
```

Doing this incrementally, everything is ok until, I add the last JSON_OBJECT function (which appears first in the query), and I can get to a resultset with the category in the first column, the group in the second ana JSON object summarising the rest. I need to have only two columns, the category in the first, and a JSON object in the second.

I would appreciate any light that can be thrown on this - I have searched high and low, and spent hours on this.

Regards,

Will.

Comment: You ideally should provide a more _minimal_ question here.  Without seeing your data, most users here won't be able to debug your query.  So, you should either post a smaller query, add some sample data/output, explain exactly where the problem is, or some combination of the above.

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for the comment. This is about as minimal as it gets. It seems I am only going to be able to collapse two tables, a child and a grandchild, into a JSON column. I'm not sure how I would provide sample data, and the output at the moment is just the error response. I will have to abandon this approach, I think.

Answer (score 1):

By sheer luck and desperation, I got it to work. I enclosed the stage that worked, combining the child and grandchild tables into a JSON column, into a view, and then used that as a child to the eventual parent.

```
    SELECT 
      requirement_category,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(requirement_group, requirement)) as requirements
    FROM
        (SELECT 
          rc.requirement_category,
          rg.requirement_group,
          JSON_OBJECT(
            'requirement_subgroup', rsg.requirement_subgroup, 
            'description', rsg.description, 'requirements', 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
              JSON_OBJECT(
              'requirement', rs.requirement, 
              'description', rs.description
              )
            )
          ) AS requirement
              FROM jobdesc_jdc.requirement_categories rc
              JOIN requirement_groups rg ON rg.requirement_category = rc.requirement_category
              JOIN requirement_subgroups rsg ON rsg.requirement_group = rg.requirement_group
              JOIN requirements rs ON rs.requirements_subgroup = rsg.requirement_subgroup
              GROUP BY rc.requirement_category , rg.requirement_group
        ) v1
    GROUP BY requirement_category
```